# Smart Cameras and Image Processing

Tags: c++, image, graphics, camera

I am very interesting in getting into graphics programming and Image processing. I am intrigued by some programs I've seen such as QR scanners that can take an image from a camera and do something with it, but I don't necessarily know where to start learning things like this. I know a decent amount of java after taking a course on the language and know the basics of c++, but am still learning and I am not opposed to having to learn a new language  and start from scratch to get into this sort of thing.  Is there any existing text or tutorial that does a fairly decent job of pointing an individual in the right direction to get started working with computer image processing?

Comment: It might help to whittle down your wish-list to a specific area of image processing that you want to do, and then be even more specific about a problem you are trying to solve.  You then look for discussions on that particular type of problem and/or ask questions about it here.  In terms of computer vision in C++, you may find it helpful to start with OpenCV.  There's a large community out there who use it, so you won't be on your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After google-ing more about what @paddy mentioned in the comments, I've decided OpenCV is the way to go for me.

Answer (score 4):

The image processing field is huge, and it's becoming larger and larger with time. Since you are a beginner in image processing, I suggest you to use a third-party toolkit that could help you with that. We use a toolkit named leadtools that might help you, since they have tutorial and good help files to implement your image processing requirements in c++. You can check this page as a start:
[Processing an Image](http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/main/clib/dllsteps/tutimgproc.htm)